# Changing image file path on image:hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently working on a portfolio website, where I have to insert a series of reference logos in a couple rows, just like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 reference">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/logo section/final/faded/adelie.png" alt="Adelie"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 reference">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/logo section/final/faded/amageme.png" alt="Amageme"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 reference">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/logo section/final/faded/bakey.png" alt="Bakey"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 reference">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/logo section/final/faded/byensdepot.png" alt="Byensdepot"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 reference">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/logo section/final/faded/dialoogle.png" alt="Dialoogle"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 reference">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/logo section/final/faded/drachmann.png" alt="Drachmann"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when hovering over a logo, I'd like to change the file path, somehow like:

```
var fadedpath = "img/logo section/final/faded/";
var colorpath = "img/logo section/final/color/";
$(".reference").hover(function(){
    $(this).attr(colorpath, filename);
}, function(){
    $(this).attr(fadedpath, filename);
});
```

What is the correct syntax to do so? Because talking about multiple files, it's not effective to change it in css one by one.

Comment: It says filename is not defined. How can I defined filename as it refers to the filename of "this"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct however your user of `attr()` is incorrect. You need to use the getter to retrieve the current `src` and then `replace()` the values.  You also need to change the attribute on the image within `.reference`, not on the `.reference` element itself. Try this:

```
var fadedpath = "img/logo section/final/faded/";
var colorpath = "img/logo section/final/color/";

$(".reference").hover(function(){
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', function(i, src) {
        return src.replace(fadedpath, colorpath);
    });
}, function(){
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', function(i, src) {
        return src.replace(colorpath, fadedpath);
    });
});
```

Also note that you shouldn't put spaces in folder names used in URLs.

Comment: Space in foldername corrected, now it's just logosection. But it says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined :-/

Comment: Thanks, perfect! But can you explain me that `function(i, src)` there please?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `replace` prototype method from `string` object. So, you need to change your code just like:

---

**REV 1 :**

- ADD `$(this).find('img')`: Sorry I am miss-reading your HTML format

---

```
var fadedpath = "/faded/";
var colorpath = "/color/";
var oldPath = '';

$(".reference").hover(function() {
    oldPath = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    $(this).find('img').attr(src, oldPath.replace(fadedpath, colorpath));

}, function() {
    oldPath = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    $(this).find('img').attr(src, oldPath.replace(colorpath, fadedpath));
});
```

Comment: After correcting some var name mistypings, it says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Comment: It said src is undefined, so I corrected like `oldPath = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
     $(this).attr('src', oldPath.replace(fadedpath, colorpath));` Now it shows no error, but it doesn't do anyithing :-/